# Open file extensions in other apps (iOS)

Tags: ios, file-type

I need to open files such as audio files (.wav, .mpg), video files (.mpeg, .avi), GIFs, PDF, etc.  I know in Android you can open file extensions in different apps (i.e opening an image):

[image]

However, I am unsure if we iOS has this functionality.  Is it possible to open file extensions in other apps?  My concern is that the user can delete default apps now, which may cause issues if trying to open an extension and the application doesn't exist.

I was thinking of just creating a custom view controller which can house the common file types, and using libraries for files that Cocoa doesn't support (i.e [GIF library](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)).  I just would detect file type and present the UI accordingly.  However, if we can always open a audio/video file in another app, I will just use external apps instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to open system's menu with the list of all applications, currently available, that are [*registered*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html) as supporting files of particular type, e.g.:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *dvc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:<...>]];
[dvc presentOptionsMenuFromRect:(CGRect){{0.f, CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame)}, CGSizeZero} inView:self.view animated:YES];
```