# How to open and view a file in an ios app from Gluon application

Tags: ios, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have Gluon Glisten AfterBurner mobile project. It is similar to a email application . I want to click on the attachment files to view it on IOS platform. Is there a way to do this using the Gluon framework.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881194/open-file-extensions-in-other-apps-ios)?

Comment: The above link refers to native IOS code to open a file. Is there way to do this from my Gluon application instead of writing native IOS code?

Comment: The closest thing you can find in Charm Down is the Share service. You could also use custom schemes, but that will require registering the apps you would use, which is not the case I think.